# change font to "times new roman"

Tags: fonts

How to change the font to "times new roman " in LaTeX?

I used

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage[left=1.5in,top=1in,right=1in,bottom=5em]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{Times New Roman}

...............................

..........................


..................
\end{document}
```

but the fonts did not change. What do I need to do?

Comment: Include `\usepackage{mathptmx}` to your preamble to load **Time Roman**. Check out this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_New_Roman#Times_Roman_and_Times_New_Roman)

Comment: got it...   \usepackage{mathptmx} is the simple way of times new roaman font..thank u.